# set /p failing to read sftp mapped file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sftp

I'm trying to write a batch file to act as an interface between Source-Insight, and Git running on a Linux server, but I'm running into an issue where the `set /p` does not seem to be working as advertised.

The batch file is supposed to run a linux script (via plink), which will check out the appropriate files into two directories, and then invoke Beyond Compare to compare the directories (note, these are on an sftp mounted drive so that dos can see them).   The directory names are dynamic, so I need the batch file to read the generated directory name from a file before passing it to Beyond Compare.   I can't seem to get this working...

I have the following lines in my batch script:

```
  @echo on 
  plink server1234 -l %user% -i %ppk_file% "cd %root%; ~/bin/compare_git_all.sh --debug --ref"
  echo "set /p dir=<%dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir"
  set /p dir=<%dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir
  echo dir="%dir%" (from %dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir)
  "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe" %dir%.refpt %dir%
  @echo off
```

My output ends up being:

```
"set /p dir=<z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.dosdir"
dir="" (from z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.dosdir)
```

So first issue (annoyance really), is that `@echo on` is not causing the commands to be echoed (which according to the pages I've google it's supposed to do...)

But what's killing me is that `%dir%` seems to be blank.   I've verified that the file contains the data I am looking for:

```
C:\>more z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.dosdir
z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.zmP8BK
```

if I run the same command from a Command Prompt, I get:

```
C:\>set dir=blank

C:\>echo %dir%
blank

C:\>set /p dir=<z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.dosdir

C:\>echo %dir%
z:\builddir\pd2\wt1\.comparegit.zmP8BK
```

So, I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what it is.   Any help would be appreciated.   (note, if it makes any difference, the batch file is being invoked from a keymapping within Source Insight)

Comment: I'd use `for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("%dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir") do set "dir=%%b"` in place of `set /p dir=<%dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir`, or more safely,  `set "dir="&for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("%dosroot%\.comparegit.dosdir") do if not defined dir set "dir=%%b"`

Comment: Is that code part of a code block (inside parenthesis) or is that the complete batch file? Instead of using `echo %dir%` you could try `set "dir"`

Comment: The code shown is part of a much larger batch file (it does things like figure out root and user based on environment, stuff I didn't think was relevant to the question).   The code block is inside of an if statement -- does that make a difference?   `ELSE IF "%dorefptr%" == "1" ( ` ... `)`.   Outside of that it's in the main context of the batch file.

Comment: @Magoo -- I am using the custom command from Source Insight.  It could potentially use some sort of emulator, which could be my problem (they don't mention anything in their documentation about it either way).   Is there a command I could use to determine if I'm in some sort of emulator?

Comment: @Magoo -- If I cut and paste your code suggestion into a dos prompt, I get `%%b was unexpected at this time.`.   I can't say I'm following what that does (I unfortunately don't have much experience with dos scripts)

Comment: `%%b was unexpected at this time` is symptomatic of executing the command directly from the prompt. That instruction is intended to be in your batch file. To run it from the prompt, replace each `%%b` with `%b`. I've no idea about the characteristics of emulators. In batch, an emulator might replace the `find` utility with the unix find-a-file command. Absolutely, in a batch file, a series of commands occurring between `(...)` known as a `code block` needs special investigation - especially where `%variable%` is used. The code needs to be quoted from the very outermost layer of nesting.